# Constraint layout can not be rendered in Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Coding a constraint layout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    style="@style/divider_style"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    swedbank:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    swedbank:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/some_image"
    style="@style/some_style"
    swedbank:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" <!-- This '+' -->
    swedbank:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    swedbank:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/divider" />   <!-- This '+' -->
```

See the comments: the plusses on those lines must be there for the android studio layout renderer to work. without them you get:

```
Couldn't resolve resource @id/divider   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

I always thought `@+id/` was for the first time you defined an id?

I've experienced IDE problems if I use +'es everywhere some years ago: With goto-definition the IDE would not know which id to go to

Tested on Android studio 2.3.3 and 3.0.1

Seeing as the auto-complete gives you plusses everywhere should i just go with that?

Comment: I think you better download the latest Android Studio 3.0.1 version which have many constraint layout design optimizations

Comment: Updated, the issue persists!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your dependencies section in the gradle
`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`